# At least one number in input field (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, validation, input, numbers

I have an input field, where user has to add his address, but I need to get at least one number (house number). How should I validate that field ? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You should post your code, so that it will be easy to solve

Comment: "at least one number" isn't enough to confirm the user has entered a house number, because they might type something like "Smith Street, Jonesville, 26000" (i.e., the one number might be a post code), or "52nd Street".

Comment: In my country, we use such a format: city, street name + street number. Example: City XYZ, Big Street 40.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question, to see if a string contains at least one number :

```
if ( string.match(/\d/) ) {
    // do something
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pEFsx/)