# Javascript - Ensure input has at least one number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So I have a `textarea` and am doing some front-end validation on it with jQuery and Regex.

The criteria for the input are as follows:

- must have 5-12 characters
- cannot contain any special characters
- needs at least one number

it is the last point that I am struggling with.

This is how I am validating the first two criteria:

```
if (charsLength < 5 || charsLength > 12) {
                       alert("Please ensure your Unique ID is between 5 and 12 characters.");
                   }
                    if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(uniqueIDContent) == false) {
                        alert('Your Unique ID contains illegal characters.');
                    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [At least one number in input field (jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364013/at-least-one-number-in-input-field-jquery)

Comment: What is the point of limiting usernames or user IDs (whatever you want to call them) like this? Especially the "at least one number" thing.

Comment: @Mike It is required for a code that is then generated...part of a clients ecommerce product - don't ask :P

Comment: @dwinnbrown Sounds pretty ludicrous to me. Anyway, I hope they're not doing this to passwords too. That would be a big no-no.

Comment: It's a physical product that they make but each needs a unique id. We're using a new solution now...surname+last 4 digits of phone number!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a lookahead to enforce presence of at least a digit in input:

```
/^(?=\D*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9 -]+$/
```

`(?=\D*\d)` is positive lookahead that asserts at least one digit is present in your field.

Comment: Ok thanks - so how exactly would I implement that into an if statement? I have a `var` called `uniqueIDContent` apologies in advance for the naïvety

Comment: Same code like you have in question i.e. `/^(?=\D*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9 -]+$/.test(uniqueIDContent) == false`

Comment: Sorry yes just figured that out *doh*

Answer (score 2):

You can use a look-ahead to ensure that a certain condition is true in the following string.

In this case, that condition is *"at least one decimal digit anywhere in the string"*, i.e. `(?=.*\d)`.

Therefore we get:

```
^(?=.*\d)[ a-zA-Z0-9-]{5, 12}$
```

This expression also includes the length check.

**Note** If you want to allow `-` in a character class, get into the habit of making it either the very first or very last character, to prevent inadvertently creating a range.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please could you explain why we are looking for 'one decimal digit'? Thanks you!

Comment: Because the look-ahead expression is fulfilled as soon as one digit is found.

Answer (score 0):

u would try it
at least a number :)

```
^(?=.*\d)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,12}
```